# Dropdown in RadGrid

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, telerik, radgrid

How can I make the "DurationType" column in my code to a dropdown menu?

I have already modified the code to show how to create the template and add the dropdown. But I can't figure out how to get the value of the dropdown and for it only to show up in the insert/edit templates, not the regular grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["GridData"] == null)
    {
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        Session.Add("GridData", table);
    }
    DefineGridStructure();
}

public class MyTemplate : ITemplate
{
    protected DropDownList dl;
    private string colname;

    public MyTemplate(string cName)
    {
        colname = cName;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        dl = new DropDownList();
        dl.ID = colname;
        dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hours", "Hours"));
        dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Days", "Days"));
        dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Weeks", "Weeks"));
        dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Months", "Months"));
        container.Controls.Add(dl);
    }

    void boolValue_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cBox = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)cBox.NamingContainer;
    }
}

private void DefineGridStructure()
{
    RadGrid grid = new RadGrid();
    grid.ID = "RadGrid1";
    grid.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(grid_NeedDataSource);
    grid.AutoGenerateEditColumn = true;
    grid.AutoGenerateDeleteColumn = true;
    grid.AllowAutomaticInserts = false;
    grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.PageSize = 15;
    grid.AllowPaging = true;
    grid.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    grid.MasterTableView.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.TopAndBottom;
    grid.AllowAutomaticDeletes = false;
    grid.AllowAutomaticUpdates = false;
    grid.InsertCommand +=grid_InsertCommand;
    grid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "RowNumber" };
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "RowNumber";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "RowNumber";
    boundColumn.ReadOnly = true;
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Size";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Size";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Description";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Description";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Quantity";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Quantity";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Duration";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Duration";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    // Added code snippet to create the dropdown list
    GridTemplateColumn objGridTemplateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
    objGridTemplateColumn.HeaderText = "DurationType";
    objGridTemplateColumn.UniqueName = "DurationType";
    objGridTemplateColumn.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate("DurationType");
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(objGridTemplateColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Amount";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Amount";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(grid);
}

private void grid_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Looking to loop through the form so i can insert the values into the datatable
}

void grid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable current = (DataTable)Session["GridData"];
    RadGrid grid = (RadGrid)sender;
    grid.DataSource = current;
}

static DataTable GetTable()
{
    //
    // Here we create a DataTable with a few columns.
    //
    // Create Datatable to store all colums
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Size", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Duration", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DurationType", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
    dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: I modified the code and added the section to create a template with a drop down and added the dropdown to DurationType column. Now when i load the page i see the dropdown, 
but i can't figure out how to get the selected value from here and if i update the code, i want to make sure when the dropdown loads, it loads with the right item selected.
Also how can i make the actual dropdown only load in the insert or edit template, and when it displays the actual grid just to show it as text?

Comment: I was able to use this to get the value, but it only gets one of them and i can't specify which row to look at it        string text = (e.Item.FindControl("DurationType") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;

Comment: Any help please, going crazy trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the existing code, I have edited few lines to replace the dropdownlist with telerik `RadComboBox`. Basically what I'm doing is, when the grid is in edit mode I'm getting the existing bindings of the text from the grid event and then binding all new set of data to the RadCombobox, finally setting the selected field as the one which I get in the event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["GridData"] == null)
    {
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        Session.Add("GridData", table);
    }
    DefineGridStructure();
}

public class MyTemplate : ITemplate
{
    protected RadComboBox dl;
    private string colname;

    public MyTemplate(string cName)
    {
        colname = cName;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        dl = new RadComboBox();
        dl.ID = colname;
        dl.DataSource=getDurationTypes();

        dl.DataTextField = "DurationTypeName";
        dl.DataValueField = "DurationTypeID";
        dl.DataBind();               
        container.Controls.Add(dl);
    }

    void boolValue_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadComboBox cBox = (RadComboBox)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)cBox.NamingContainer;
    }
}

private void DefineGridStructure()
{
    RadGrid grid = new RadGrid();
    grid.ID = "RadGrid1";
    grid.NeedDataSource += new    GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(grid_NeedDataSource);
    grid.ItemDataBound +=new GridItemEventHandler();
    grid.AutoGenerateEditColumn = true;
    grid.AutoGenerateDeleteColumn = true;
    grid.AllowAutomaticInserts = false;
    grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.PageSize = 15;
    grid.AllowPaging = true;
    grid.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    grid.MasterTableView.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.TopAndBottom;
    grid.AllowAutomaticDeletes = false;
    grid.AllowAutomaticUpdates = false;
    grid.InsertCommand +=grid_InsertCommand;
    grid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "RowNumber" };
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "RowNumber";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "RowNumber";
    boundColumn.ReadOnly = true;
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Size";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Size";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Description";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Description";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Quantity";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Quantity";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Duration";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Duration";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    // Added code snippet to create the dropdown list
    GridTemplateColumn objGridTemplateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
    objGridTemplateColumn.HeaderText = "DurationType";
    objGridTemplateColumn.UniqueName = "DurationType";
    objGridTemplateColumn.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate("DurationType");
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(objGridTemplateColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Amount";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Amount";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(grid);
}

private void grid_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Looking to loop through the form so i can insert the values into the datatable
}

void grid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable current = (DataTable)Session["GridData"];
    RadGrid grid = (RadGrid)sender;
    grid.DataSource = current;
}

static DataTable GetTable()
{
    //
    // Here we create a DataTable with a few columns.
    //
    // Create Datatable to store all colums
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Size", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Duration", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DurationType", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
    dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
}
```

`ItemDataBound` event for displaying the ItemTemplate when it is in edit mode, RadcomboBox will appear when the grid is in editmode.

```
  protected void Grid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)  
    {
    string DurationName;
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem myGridItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        //Changing the DurationName field to Combobox in EDITMODE
        if (myGridItem.IsInEditMode)
        {
            GridEditableItem edititem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            int userId = Convert.ToInt16(edititem.GetDataKeyValue("RowNumber"));
            RadComboBoxItem selectedItem = new RadComboBoxItem(); 
            RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)myGridItem["DurationType"].FindControl("colname");
            DurationName= DataBinder.Eval(myGridItem.DataItem, "DurationType").ToString();
            combo.DataSource = roles.GetRoles();
            combo.DataTextField = "DurationType";
            combo.DataValueField = "DurationID";
            combo.DataBind();
            selectedItem = combo.FindItemByText(DurationName);
            combo.SelectedIndex = selectedItem.Index;
        }
      }
    }
```

This method will return data for binding it with radcombobox(dropdownlist)

```
private DataTable getDurationTypes()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("DurationTypeID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("DurationTypeName", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(1, "Hours");
    table.Rows.Add(2, "Days");
    table.Rows.Add(3, "Weeks");
    table.Rows.Add(4, "Months");
    return table;
 }
```